# laptop shuts off out of sudden when the fan suddenly stops spinning

Tags: laptop, shutdown, fan, malware, adware

My laptop recently got an issue. it will shuts down during loading when I turn it off repeatedly. it got worse during time, previously, if it happens, next try the laptop would work fine, but now, I need to try like 10 times and gets laptop shut off until it works and nothing happens until i shut it down. then next day, when try to turn it on, problem appears again(like today). again, previously when I turn it on again, the screen would be fine too, but now, the time it works, the screen will go off and then i need to trick my laptop to go to sleep and then when it is on again, the screen will be ok. first thing came to my thought was Malware stuff. so for a period of time after I removed some malware from my system it healed but now it broke gain and now when I try detecting adware/malware in my system, the software (Loaris) detects 6 registry entry like :

```
HKCR\interface.....Adware.RPL.Gen.Bot
```

the weird thing is after like 3 hours , the internal CPU fan stops spinning suddenly even if i put it in sleep, it will stops spinning  with a noise and then laptop shuts off and then several seconds later, the laptop shuts off. in next try, it wont be spinning again and it requires me to on and off again many times to get a chance for my fan to spin again.

Comment: The fan could have a loose connector or it could be dirty.  See if you can see the connector at the end of the fan wire and whether it is secure.  Use compressed air to blow out the fan area and blow dust off the blades.  Verify that the blades spin freely.  Does it make any difference whether you are operating on battery power or plugged in?  What is the model and age of the laptop?  Does the problem ever happen soon after turning it on for the first time after resting overnight or does it happen only after it's been running for awhile?

Comment: @fixer1234 its a Vaio TT series, i bought it by 2009, it was almost good all the time, except few times minor screen noise. but since last year, several times i got the problem in a very lighter case of what i explained above. 2-3 months ago when it started to act extreamly annoying, i removed battery and it was fine for several days but it happened again. i dont know how to explain it,  but its like when it works for a period of time, no matter in what mode, sleep mode or highly active,

Comment: @fixer1234 the fan stops and then shuts off. when trying to turn on, fan wont go on except i spend like hours turning on and off, sometime les than an hour sometimes like last night, took me5 hours.

Comment: I suspect turning it on and off is doing little more than helping you vent frustration and feel like you're affecting something.  It could be a flaky power problem, particularly a bad connection to the fan.  It could be a temperature problem, either because the fan shuts off or the fan shuts off because the temperature is affecting a connection or solder joint.  It could be a bad temperature sensor.  It could be something else and the fan is just another symptom.  It doesn't sound like the kind of problem that would be caused by malware.

Comment: If the frequency or severity is getting worse, it would more likely be a sign of physical deterioration than a software condition.  The laptop isn't young.  This kind of thing can be tedious to diagnose from afar.  I'd suggest taking it in for service but at the laptop's age, you might be throwing good money after bad.  You might be better off putting the service cost toward a new laptop.

Comment: @fixer1234 now i took the battery out and directy connevted the laptop by its charger to AC. seems working fine so far for several hours. feel kinda helpless. oh god

Comment: @fixer1234 but since by time goes, the system can get more infected, it could be still a software situation too.

Comment: The nature of the problem doesn't sound software related and if it was, it wouldn't solve itself and recur periodically.  I sounds like hardware.  It might be something that can be fixed.  If you know your way around, you can check a few of the possibilities.  If it needs service, there is usually a hefty diagnostic fee just to open the case, then parts and labor if it can be repaired.  Your laptop is at the age where other things may start failing even if you fix this problem.  Weigh how much you want to spend on the possibility of short-term repair vs. putting it toward a new one.

Comment: On a laptop, almost any repair that isn't a damaged keyboard, screen, battery/charger problem, or user-replaceable part like hard disk or RAM, entails replacing the system board unless it is something "trivial" like blowing off the fan or tightening a connector.  That's the most cost-effective way for shops to handle most repairs (from their perspective).

Comment: If you do get a new computer, you can easily salvage you files, even if the old laptop isn't working.  If the hard disk is still in good condition, you can stick it in an inexpensive external case and use it as a USB drive for backup.

Comment: Have you monitored you CPU temperature during shutdowns?

Comment: @Mast no i didnt. how to? plus, it happens suddenly, I cant be prepared or there is someway to record the temperature and then later review it later?

Comment: IM A HONEST MAN AT LEAST!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need replacement of this faulty fan.

Comment: Fans can get loaded up with dust, etc., which affects how well they work, and can even bind up.  But if they're having a problem, they don't recover and work fine for awhile.  It's likely that whatever is going on would affect a replacement fan the same way unless it's just a bad or dirty connector.

Comment: Of-course. But if dust is not the cause, probably issue is faulty fan.

Comment: Faulty fans don't typically run intermittently when they receive power.  That's not a normal failure mode.  If it is not binding and working free (dirty), the problem is probably not the fan, itself.